# Problems with calling a function in the HTML file using Angular JS

Tags: javascript, java, html, angularjs

I am fairly new with AngularJS. I'm trying to do something simple for the moment. I created a table with some text I'll have to search with, a reset button (In my program is called "Pulisci") and some panels I'll have to use later. The problem is that, if I call the function I created for resetting the page, the panels mysteriously stop working. I'm banging my head on this since last week.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="sbi">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        table,
        td {
            border-width: 2px;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            padding: 15px;
            color: #000000;
            text-align: center;
        }

        table.pos_fixed1 {
            position: relative;
            top: 30px;
            left: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <form name="form">
        <table summary="" width="10%" class="pos_fixed1" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td>Code Subinstaller<br><input name="codeSub" type="text" ng-model="codeSub"></td>
                <td>Stato<br>
                    <select>
                    <option value="1">...</option>
                    <option value="2">WHITE LIST</option>
                    <option value="3">GRAY LIST</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Nome Sub Installer<input name="nomeSub" type="text" ng-model="nomeSub"></td>
                <td>Cognome Sub Installer<input name="cognSub" type="text" ng-model="cognSub"></td>
                <td>Codice Fiscale<input name="codFisc" type="text" ng- model="codFisc"> </td>
            </tr>
        </table><br>
        <button class="btn btn-wide btn-default.active.focus" data-ng- click="">Cerca</button>
        <button class="btn btn-wide btn-default.active.focus" data-ng- click="reset()">Pulisci</button>
    </form><br><br>
    <section ng-controller="PanelController as panel">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li ng-class="{ active:panel.isSelected(1) }"> <a href ng- click="panel.selectTab(1)">Description</a></li>
            <li ng-class="{ active:panel.isSelected(2) }"> <a href ng- click="panel.selectTab(2)">Specifications</a></li>
            <li ng-class="{ active:panel.isSelected(3) }"> <a href ng- click="panel.selectTab(3)">Reviews</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="panel" ng-show="panel.isSelected(1)">
            <h4>Description </h4>
            <p>wtf</p>
        </div>
        <div class="panel" ng-show="panel.isSelected(2)">
            <h4>Idk</h4>
            <p>Idc</p>
        </div>
        <div class="panel" ng-show="panel.isSelected(3)">
            <h4>APPARI</h4>
            <p>???</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myapp.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**JS**

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('sbi', []);
    app.controller('PanelController', function() {
        this.tab = 1;
        this.selectTab = function(setTab) {
            this.tab = setTab;
        };
        this.isSelected = function(checkTab) {
            return this.tab === checkTab;
        };
    });
})();

(function($scope) {
    var app = angular.module('sbi', []);

    function MyCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.reset = function() {
            $scope.requiredField = '';
        };
    };
});
```

How can I make the Reset() and the panels work simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have re-initialized your angular module.

Initializing your angular module

```
var app = angular.module('sbi', []);
```

Second argument in `angular.module()` is for injecting the required dependency for the module. And hence should be done only once.

In your code, you have again initialized your module.

```
(function () {
    //initialization
    var app = angular.module('sbi', []);

    app.controller('PanelController', function () {
        this.tab = 1;

        this.selectTab = function (setTab) {
            this.tab = setTab;
        };
        this.isSelected = function (checkTab) {
            return this.tab === checkTab;
        };
    });
})();

(function ($scope) {

    //edit in your code
    //re-using the already initialized module
    var app = angular.module('sbi');

    function MyCtrl($scope) {

        $scope.reset = function () {
            $scope.requiredField = '';

        };
    };
});
```

You should not pass the second argument as parameter.

Reusing your angular module

```
var app = angular.module('sbi');
```

**EDIT :**

Try the following code :

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('sbi', []);

    app.controller('PanelController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.tab = 1;

        $scope.selectTab = function (setTab) {
            $scope.tab = setTab;
        };

        $scope.isSelected = function (checkTab) {
            return $scope.tab === checkTab;
        };

        $scope.reset = function () {
            $scope.requiredField = '';
        };
    }]);
})();
```

Comment: If i remove the    var app = angular.module('sbi', []);); from the myCtrl function, the reset() button doesn't work. How should my JS look?

Comment: I've made changes in my answer. Have a look.

Comment: Can you see any errors in developer console in browser...??

Comment: I tried your example and I called <div data-ng-controller="MyCtrl"> after the <form name="form">; that way, nothing (both reset() and panels) work...

Comment: It says "Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/ng/areq?p0=MyCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined"

Comment: only use one `var app= angular.module`. remove the var app in your second function so that it is only `angular.module('sbi')`. The problem is you are reinitialising the `sbi` module and it overwrites the first

Comment: I tried to make it "(function ($scope) {

    var app = angular.module('sbi');

    app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

        $scope.reset = function () {
            $scope.requiredField = '';

        };
    };
});"

Comment: @Tushortz I'm gonna try it now!

Comment: Even if I use `angular.module('sbi')` nothing seem to be willing to work.

Comment: @user7900468  I have added a new code. Can you please try that.

Comment: Check your code `data-ng- click`. Shouldn't it be `data-ng-click` also view the console and see what error message it is giving. It will be very useful to diagnose the problem @user7900468

Comment: @Tushortz there are no spaces, i think it's just something happened while i was copy pasteing it here.

Answer (score 0):

There is something you are clearly missing here: your `reset` function is attached to... nothing.

The `MyCtrl` function is never called (from what we've seen), and the `$scope` variable is not injected the Angular-way. Actually, nothing here is in the Angular way. Let me try to adjust this so you understand what you should aim for.

First of all, as @Akshay mentioned, there is a huge difference between `angular.module('something', [])` and `angular.module('something')`, but they already pointed that out in their response.

Then, your `MyCtrl` hasn't been registered as a controller in Angular. You just defined the function, you were missing these lines:

```
var app = angular.module('sbi');

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.reset = function () {
        $scope.requiredField = '';

    };
};

// This controller will be known as 'MyCtrl'
app.controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);
```

This should work. Note that you won't be needing the surrounding `(function ($scope) {...})` as it won't be executed correctly.

Then, you will have to tell Angular to *use* that controller in that specific part of your page:

```
<!-- Adding the ng-controller directive here -->
<form name="form" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    ...
    <button class="btn btn-wide btn-default.active.focus" data-ng-click="reset()">Pulisci</button>
</form>
```

Then, you will be able to handle your `requiredField` variable as you wish.

Comment: The Reset() button doesn't work anyway.
The console of my browser doesn't say anything.

Comment: What should it do? Because, in your case, it just sets the `requiredField` scope variable to an empty string.

Comment: What should I put in it?

Comment: It seems you just want to reset the form, plain and all. You should take a look at [this documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms), the reset button is pretty much self-explanatory: it resets the variable used in the form `ng-model`.